# Java: Find out which observer is listening

Tags: java, events, jakarta-ee, java-7, observer-pattern

I am maintaining a software which I have not written. I know only a few parts of it.
Now I have found a method, which fires an event.

```
public void cleanup(){
    if(entity!=null) workflowCleanupEvent.fire(entity);
    setEntity(null);
}
```

Is there a way to find out who is listening on that event?

Using Eclipse Juno R2 and Java 1.7.

Regards
LStrike

Comment: Do you use an event bus or similar mechanism to broadcast events ? regardless of that there should be an instance which holds listener registrations for that event. find that class and check who registers the event listeners there. probably you will see a list of listeners there.

Comment: The application is running on jboss7 if that helps.

Comment: not really, it doesn't matter where the application is deployed and running in this context. what you need is to find out who registers the listeners for that event type. first find out who implements that listener type. I guess you know how to do it in Eclipse right.

Comment: I am not sure where my observers are registered. Could you tell me how to find them with eclipse, I'm new to Java EE and everything around.

Answer (score 0):

The way of knowing which Objects are listening in on the event, is using the list of listeners.

If there are listeners, they must have registered somewhere, so I would start by figuring out who is calling the registering method. 
Having identified that, you should be able to access a list/map of the objects that are registered to receive events.

It might help if you provide us with more details on the Class corresponding to the `workflowCleanupEvent`.